# Check if HTML <p> tag contains text, and then change background color

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get help with the question above.

I tried doing:

```
var string = document.getElementById('t')
if(string.includes("ALARM"))
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

The html tag is

Current sensor data: 140 |ALARM

Thanks for help

Comment: `getElementById()` returns an element not a string. You need to check the content of that element. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = document.getElementById('t')
```

The above line gave you the element with `id='t'`

```
var string = document.getElementById('t').innerText;
```

The above line will give you the inner text of that HTML element

You will have to make this one change

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is checking for the presence of ANY text in the element - then you can use the `:empty pseudo-selector`....

If you  are checking for the presence of specific text in the element - then you will need the javascript solutions provided by the other solutions.

However in the interest of a css solution - the :empty selector is a CSS selector that triggers when the element is empty (or contains only a comment) - note that whitespace DOES count as content so its not a perfect option....

The second and third p elements are empty - even though the third has a comment

```css
p { 
  height: 16px;
}

p:empty { 
  border :solid 1px red
}
```

```html
<p>I have content</p>

<p></p>

<p><!-- I do not have content--></p>

<p>I have content</p>
```

If you want the p with the content to be highlighted - then you can use the `:not` selector  in combination with the `:empty` selector;

```css
p {
  height: 20px;
}

p:empty {
  border: dashed 1px lightgrey; 
}

p:not(:empty) {
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 1px red; 
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p></p>

<p>ALARM</p>

<p></p>
```